# How to determine lines of pyspark code involved in failed stage?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a failed execution stage due to out of memory error. How do I determine lines of pyspark source code responsible for failed stage?

I have used Web UI to view physical plan, which provides some insight because it references variable names from source code. I have also looked at DAG for failing stage. However, I have been unable to connect the details of the DAG with the physical plan.

I am using Pyspark 2.4.3 and I am using the Dataframe API.

Comment: Any error you could share ?

Comment: Listed under failure reason for stage: `org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 4 `

Comment: Listed under failure reason for retry: `org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to /172.20.0.5:41795`

Comment: Listed for failed task in retry stage failure: `FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(1, 172.20.0.5, 43141, None), shuffleId=4, mapId=14, reduceId=14, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to /172.20.0.5:43141
 at `

Comment: Listed for failed task in original stage failure: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: please specify the data size and executor memory in the question. Also, specify any Spark configuration you have done.

Answer (score 0):

the last error you mentionned : `Java heap space`. You need to allow more ressources to your executors. There is not 1 line failling, it is a whole !

Comment: Even with more resources, it simply fails at a later stage. Is there a way to pinpoint what parts of code taking up a large percentage of the resources? I suspect data skew issues due to looking at event timeline for failing stage but it's hard to pinpoint which dataframe is involved with the failing stage to test this hypothesis.

Comment: the easy solution, you save your dataframe after each transformation and see which one is failling.Jave heap space error are not related to one particular line. It is a whole as I said. Therefore, you will have to cut your process in piece to see which transformation is blocking you.

Comment: thank you for the response. any strategies for efficiently doing this when your python script is 604 lines? I'm considering trying to find the amount of resources to throw at it such that it succeeds and using the web UI stats to determine what is hogging up most of the resources.

Comment: @admas1413 proceed by dichotomy maybe !